# Como cancelar a ação da tag a?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

Preciso cancelar a ação da âncora depois que eu mando um alerta. Como faço isso?

Tentei com `e.eventDefault()`. Tentei com o `window.location` para redirecionar a página para o padrão e não estou obtendo o resultado que eu quero.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" defer>
    function alertPages() {  
        alert("Página em contrução")

        const a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
        a.preventDefault()     
    }   
</script>

<a href="./about.html" onclick="alertPages()">About</a>
<a href="./contact.html" onclick="alertPages()">Contato</a>
```

Ou seja preciso que ao clicar no link, exiba a mensageme não redirecione para a página.

Comment: não deveria ser: `preventDefault()`?

Comment: testou com o `preventDefault()` e não funcionou?

Comment: @Danizavtz claro que não, `preventDefault` é para eventos, entao ele teria que adicionar um _eventListener_ para a tag `a` . Detalhe que `getElementsByTagName` retorna um _HTMLCollection_.

Comment: mas eu adicionei ali, pq simplesmente já tentei com event listener também e não foi.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` retorna um _HTMLCollection_, voce teria que converter e iterar para adicionar um _event listener_.

Comment: @CmteCardeal estou sem poder depurar, por isso eu perguntei. sry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o que quer é que a página não siga o fluxo normal *(carregar a página com a url referida)*, uma forma de fazer isso seria simplesmente alterar o conteúdo do link, se entendi bem a pergunta:

```js
function alertPages() {
  let a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].setAttribute('href', '#');
  }
  alert("Página em contrução");
}
```

```html
<a href="./about.html" onclick="alertPages()">About</a>
<a href="./contact.html" onclick="alertPages()">Contato</a>
```

Comment: @UelberHenrique Fique atento que esse código vai afetar todas as tags `<a>` quando clicar em qualquer uma que estiver a função `alertPages`. Todas as tags `<a>` vão ter o atributo `href` alterado para `#`.

Comment: @CmteCardeal Isso mesmo, bem lembrado, eu criei o exemplo no código  postado, esse código irá alterar todos os links das tag `a` existentes no documento, se não quer esse comportamento, basta colocar uma **classe** ou um **id** nas tags que deseja que esse comportamento ocorra!

Comment: Ok, Muito obrigado a todos.